# Error - Must specify the name in the CustomMetadataType.CustomMetadata format - Custom Metadata Loader app

Tags: custom-metadata

I've just deployed the [Custom Metadata Loader](https://github.com/haripriyamurthy/CustomMetadataLoader) app to my sandbox and am trying to load my first batch of records for my Custom Metadata Type `Interchange_Table__mdt`.

When I select the CSV containing my records, the Metadata Type from the type picklist and click Create custom metadata, I get the following error

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Must specify the name in the CustomMetadataType.CustomMetadata format, Name:Interchange_Table., Delimiter:. faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=
>   Error is in expression '{!createCustomMetadata}' in component  in page custommetadatarecorduploader: Class.MetadataService.MetadataPort.createMetadata: line 9254, column 1
>   Class.MetadataUtil.createMetadataAndValidate: line 116, column 1
>   Class.MetadataUtil.transformToCustomMetadataAndCreate: line 83, column 1
>   Class.CustomMetadataUploadController.importCSVFileAndCreateCmdRecords: line 120, column 1
>   Class.CustomMetadataUploadController.createCustomMetadata: line 45, column 1

My spreadsheet looks like this

[image: metadata records example]

and I can't see any significant difference between this and the sample data which is included in the Github repository which looks like this so I can't work out what's causing the error?

[image: sample data]

I've also opened an issue with this question in the GitHub repository for the app [here](https://github.com/haripriyamurthy/CustomMetadataLoader/issues/3) & posted the question in the Custom Metadata Types Success Group [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001t77&fId=0D53000002bkidW). I will update this question if I get an answer on either site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the `.`'s in my Label name, as explained by the app's creator [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?fId=0D53000002bkidW&g=0F9300000001t77).

> "The app tries to default the dev name to the modified label (removing spaces) if [the] name is not provided. Since this label is not of the right format, it fails. So try to add a [developer] name column to your csv and use the right format for the name."

The final format was

[image: updated formatting]

*The date format also needed updating to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSZ. The updated field API names were only necessary because of changes that I'd made in my org, after posting the first screenshot.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by not prepending the custom MDT name to the custom mdt record. So if the Custom Metadata Type name is My_Custom_Metadata__c, and the individual record name (label) is My Record, the developername should be:

```
customMetadata.fullName = My_Custom_Metadata.My_Record
```